# can I get rid of the GPL-v3 LICENCE file if I use GPL-v3 licensed code but declare it in `package.json`?

Tags: npm, licensing, gpl

I've been working with a [project](https://github.com/KnowsCount/qiokian) lately involving  the usage of `live2d`. `live2d`, however, is licensed under GPLv3, so in my understanding I must include the GPLv3 licence file in my repository.

However, the file is very large in size—to wit, 35kb. This is takes even more storage than my code... So, can I get rid of the license file, whilst making sure I have declared it in my `package.json` like `"license": "GPLv3",`?

Answer (score 4):

You must keep the whole license. Quoting from [Section 4, "Conveying Verbatim Copies"](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html#section4) of the GPL:

> You may convey verbatim copies of the Program's source code as you receive it, in any medium, provided that you [...] give all recipients a copy of this License along with the Program.